# Puppeteer infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a website to scrape and what I need to scrape is inside a **div** that has an id **left_container_scroll** that contains multiple **a tags**. This div has the infinite scroll on it and I can't make it work. I am trying to make the program scroll in that div.

I have tried to do something like this, but I get an error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: elem is not defined

```
htmlTag = '#left_container_scroll';

//I think I am doing something wrong here
let elem = await page.evaluate((htmlTag)=> {
    return document.querySelector(htmlTag);
})

previousHeight =  await page.evaluate("elem.scrollHeight");
await page.evaluate("window.scrollTo(0,elem.scrollHeight)");
await page.waitForFunction(`elem.scrollHeight > ${previousHeight}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of this JavaScript code runs inside the browser, some inside the Node.js runtime, and they can't see each other's variables.

For example, `page.evaluate("elem.scrollheight")` cannot see the `elem` variable you've set above, since the variable is inside the Node.js runtime, and the code `elem.scrollheight` is being ran inside the browser (similar issue also with `htmlTag` earlier).
To pass values from Node.js to the browser, you would usually give additional arguments to `page.evaluate`.

Something like this might work (haven't tested if the scrolling works as intended, but at least Puppeteer runs the code)

```
// returns a Puppeteer ElementHandle (not browser DOM element)
let elem = await page.$(htmlTag)
// passes the ElementHandle back to the browser code (Puppeteer converts it back to DOM element)
let previousHeight = await page.evaluate(e => e.scrollHeight, elem)
// again, pass ElementHandle
await page.evaluate(e => window.scrollTo(0, e.scrollHeight), elem)
// pass both ElementHandle and previousHeight to the browser side
await page.waitForFunction((e, ph) => e.scrollHeight > ph, {}, elem, previousHeight)
```

Comment: It still gives me this error: TimeoutError: waiting for function failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Comment: Oops, it looks like `waitForFunction` wants an extra `options` argument, so it should be `page.waitForFunction((e, ph) => e.scrollHeight > ph, {}, elem, previousHeight)` (fixed also above).

Comment: Do you know if the "infinite scroll" code on the page is working as intended? One way to debug this would be to add ` {headless: false}` to `puppeteer.launch` (so you can see what's happening, and see the developer tools console), and then log something inside the waiting function, like `await page.waitForFunction((e, ph) => { console.log("Current scrollHeight:", e.scrollHeight, " previousHeight:", ph); return e.scrollHeight > ph; }, {}, elem, previousHeight)`.

Comment: The infinite scroll is not working, it takes only the data that is loaded together with the page, it is not scrolling down to load new data ...

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what's happening, but one possibility that comes to mind is that our call to `window.scrollTo` happens before the infinite scroll code on the page has actually added the event listener for `scroll` events. I guess you could test this by adding `window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight)` to the `waitForFunction` part (so it's called repeatedly by Puppeteer)

Comment: I'm guessing the data for infinite scrolling isn't immediately available after scrolling, and takes a while for new network request(s) to settle. Try adding a [`.waitForNavigation`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions). (Do note the example in the docs, you have to call it **before** the action (scrolling) and wait for its promise **after** the action)

Answer (score 1):

Made a quite simple solution last time I was webscraping, hopefully it will help out!

```
let lastHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');

while (true) {
    await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000); // sleep a bit
    let newHeight = await page.evaluate('document.body.scrollHeight');
    if (newHeight === lastHeight) {
        break;
    }
    lastHeight = newHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take in consideration the element you want to pull, I assume that using infinite scrolling you are looking to get more element. I would set a base counter of the element you want pull, then have a loop that checks if the previous element count is equal to the new element count, this way, you can break the loop then extract the data you want. In my case, I'd set another check for element_limit e.g. 100, regardless if the loop is done or not, it'll break the loop. You may also want to consider having random timeouts between 1-5secs, this will at least give your script time for the page to load, remember that not all pages are created equally, and the network connection is also a concern.